# Best way to convert three bytes to an unsigned integer, from a binary file?

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to convert three bytes to an unsigned integer, from a binary file?

This is my current solution, do you know a better one?

```
a, b, c = file.read(3).unpack("C*")
a << 16 | b << 8 | c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooh..fun:

```
file.read(3).unpack("C*").inject { |r, n| r << 8 | n }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the BinData gem

```
require 'bindata'
n = BinData::Uint24be.read(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all with [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112) if you didn't mind added an extra byte yourself:

```
n = *("\x00" + file.read(3)).unpack('N')
```

I don't know if that qualifies as better, that's pretty subjective.

Comment: I see, by adding the extra byte you're converting it a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @skiffr: yes, you need four bytes to unpack it directly rather than manually fiddling with the bits.